# If else loop is not working/ element exists: cypress automation

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, cypress

[image]I am new to cypress. I read some of the other if-else cypress related questions and yet fail to understand whats wrong with my code.

What I am trying to accomplish: if "There are no results" found on the page, then "mark as certified" should not exist. If "there are no results" not found on the page, user clicks on a "select all" checkbox, "mark as certified" should exist and user should click it.

Here is the code I have:

```
const $el=Cypress.$('.Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0 jhYDmS TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1 ihRiqU');
       if($el.length){
        cy.log($el.length);
        cy.get('Mark as Certified').should('not.exist');
       } else{
        cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').click();
        cy.get('.hZDZBR > .Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0').contains('Mark as Certified');
        cy.get('.hZDZBR').click();
       }
```

Currently, even if "there are no results" is found on the page, cypress enters the else loop and tries to locate the select all checkbox.
How can I correct my code?
Thanks!

Hi, 
I edited my code again, also got rid of the red mark that cypress was showing. The way to do it was `const $el=Cypress.$(['.Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0.jhYDmS.TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1.ihRiqU']);`
That being done, now when cypress does not find this $el, it just stops and still does not enter the else loop!
Here is the updated code i have:

````
javascript
const $el=Cypress.$(['.Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0.jhYDmS.TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1.ihRiqU']);
       //const $el=cy.get('.hwGfvi');
       if($el.size==1){
        cy.log($el.size);
        cy.get('.hZDZBR').should('not.exist');
        cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').should('not.exist');
       } else if($el.size==0){
        cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').click();
        cy.get('.hZDZBR > .Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0').contains('Mark as Certified');
        cy.get('.hZDZBR').click();
       }
    ```
So i updated my code to:

```javascript
it("User can set certification for multiple users at once",()=>{
       cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .RadioButton__StyledRadioButton-sc-1j2qp2u-1').click(); //clicking Non-certified button
       const $el=Cypress.$('[class="Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0.jhYDmS.TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1.ihRiqU"]');
       cy.get("body").then($body =>{
        if ($body.find($el.length>0)) {
         cy.log('in if loop');
         cy.log($el.length);
         cy.get('.hZDZBR').should('not.exist');
         cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').should('not.exist');
        } else {
        cy.log('in else loop');
        cy.log($el.length);
        cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').click();
        cy.get('.hZDZBR').click();
      }
     })
    })
````

But when the element `$el` is not found (and it logs `$el.length=0` which is correct), it still tries to execute the if loop, whereas it should be in else loop...any ideas on how to resolve this?Thanks!

Here is my latest corrected code since `$body.find($el.length>0))` always evaluates to true:

````
javascript

cy.get("body").then($body =>{
        if ($body.find($el).length>0) {
         cy.log('in if loop');
         cy.log($body.find($el).length);
         cy.get('.hZDZBR').should('not.exist');
         cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').should('not.exist');
        } else if($body.find($el).length==0){
        cy.log('in else loop');
        cy.log($body.find($el).length);
        cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').click();
        cy.get('.hZDZBR').click();
      }
    ```
   However, what happens now is that it gets the length as 0 and therefore enters else loop, but I can see that the element exists on the web page and yet it gets the length as 0..how shall I resolve this..?!

For reference, this is the element whose existence I am testing, so the if-else depends on the length/existence of this element:

```javascript
<p class="Typographystyles__StyledTypography-oqatwk-0 hwGfvi TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1 ihRiqU">There are no more results.</p>
````

Comment: There is no "else if" in Javascript, you need to leave out if after else.

Comment: @pavelsaman thanks for pointing it out! my problem still remains, even though the element "There are no more results" exists on the web page, it still gets the length as 0 and therefore enters the else block..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$()` is equal to `findelement(by.css(''))`. And in your case the locator is:

```
.Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0 jhYDmS TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1 ihRiqU
```

which means find the element with the class name as `Typography...`.

But this is not a valid locator as it contains space after `Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0`. Instead, you could use locator as:

```
[class="Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0 jhYDmS TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1 ihRiqU"]
```

and also as per cypress:

`cy.get()` is same as `$()`, so even that expects a CSS locator.

So `cy.get('Mark as Certified')` is not valid locator.

Fix all these errors, and read more about CSS locators

**And about the loop, print the `$a.length` and see its value**

References:

- https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$.html#Syntax
- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Synta

Comment: Thanks for your help! There is one part where I am still stuck:

Comment: Please comment what you are stuck with , I will try to help

Comment: ```javascript
const $el=Cypress.$(class="Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0 jhYDmS TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1 ihRiqU");
```
There is some syntax error in my statement and I am unable to fix it as cypress says missing { near the = after class.
It shows a red mark under the =

Comment: @RenukaA still it's invalid locator , read about css locator you should put a square bracket for attribute. So the valid locator would be $([class="whateveritis"])

Comment: I think I know what you are referring to: so there are three spaces in the class, meaning its not actually one single class but a combination of 4 classes, and should there fore be combined with a .dot 
Please could you take a look at the image in my edited question, there is a red mark under the = sign..so I have written something wrong there...
This is what i have written (same as the image, I am just writing it here):
````const $el=Cypress.$([class='Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0.jhYDmS.TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1.ihRiqU']);````
Many thanks!

Comment: when I put cursor near the red mark which is near the =, cypress says, '{ ' expected...

Comment: any suggestion on how I can resolve this? The element is:`<p class="Typographystyles__StyledTypography-oqatwk-0 hwGfvi TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1 ihRiqU">There are good results.</p>` Just for your reference. How can I resolve this red mark that cypress wants me to correct..?

Comment: plese put the full html , its hard to tell one by one

Comment: please refer to my edit. I corrected the red mark. But cypress still just stops in the if block when it doesnt find the element and still doesnt enter the else loop

Comment: @RenukaA `const $el=Cypress.$('[class="Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0.jhYDmS.TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1.ihRiqU"]');` use this one

Comment: you are absolutely right about the selector! Thanks so much! My if-else-element exists problem still persists though, still stuck

Comment: why are you using if `($body.find($el.length>0)) {` use `if($el.length){`

Comment: I get your point, because `($body.find($el.length>0))` always evaluates to true..so I have updated the code yet again; but what happens now is that, it gets the length as 0 and enters else loop but I can see the element exists on the web page and yet it gets the length as 0..how can I resolve this?